# Can I add some HTML in my SO Profile 'About me' text box to show some button from linkedin?

Tags: support, design, profile-page

In my SO profile, I tried to do Edit profile and there in "About Me" text box, I tried to paste a HTML code as below provided by linkedin.com to display a button which would link to my profile on linkedin. But it does not seem to work on SO. 
This is the html code:

```
<a href="http://in.linkedin.com/in/ajitsdeshpande" >
    <img src="http://www.linkedin.com/img/webpromo/btn_myprofile_160x33.png" width="160" height="33" border="0" alt="View Ajit Deshpande's profile on LinkedIn">
</a>
```

1. When I checked [the html tags allowed by SO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1777/what-html-tags-are-allowed), I found I had only the whitelisted tags allowed. So does this kind of thing I am trying to do work on SO.
2. If yes how can I get it working?

Comment: Just a side note: you shouldn't use the `alt` attribute this way; use `title` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try it without the `border` attribute in the `img` tag.  The entire tag is getting stripped, not just the disallowed attribute.

Answer (score 2):

Hmm. Might as well actually show it working...

```
<a href="http://in.linkedin.com/in/ajitsdeshpande" >
    <img src="https://www.linkedin.com/img/webpromo/btn_myprofile_160x33.png" width="160" height="33" alt="View Ajit Deshpande's profile on LinkedIn">
</a>
```

[image: View Ajit Deshpande's profile on LinkedIn]

Okay, aside from the small problems of (a) using the wrong pronoun and (b) having the funky "underline", it seems to work reasonably well.