# How can I add a LinkedIn plugin script in a Stack Overflow profile's "About Me"?

Tags: support, profile-page

I want to add my LinkedIn ID plugin to my Stack Overflow profile. I generated the plugin script, but how can I add this here?

```
<script src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="IN/MemberProfile" data-id="https://www.linkedin.com/in/<linkedinID>" data-format="inline" data-related="false"></script>
```

Or HTML

```
<a href="https://bd.linkedin.com/pub/<name>/5a/135/489"><img src="https://static.licdn.com/scds/common/u/img/webpromo/btn_viewmy_160x33.png" width="160" height="33" border="0" alt="View <name>'s profile on LinkedIn"/></a>
```

Something like this:
[image]

Comment: Closely related (possibly a duplicate): [Can I add some HTML in my SO Profile 'About me' text box to show some button from linkedin?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/49216/262755)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't add arbitrary JavaScript to the "About Me" section of your profile.

More explicitly, `<script>` is not one of the [Stack Exchange white-listed HTML tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1777/what-html-tags-are-allowed-on-stack-exchange-sites).

`<a href...>` and `<img...>` are allowed, but they both have some specific limitations on attributes. See the aforementioned FAQ listing.

Comment: Markdown is allowed in profiles; probably a better option for formatting than HTML.