# How to add profile of multiple networks inside About Me?

Tags: support, profile-page

Can someone tell me, please, how to add the widget of multiple networks:

[image]

Is it by the same principle as [LinkedIn plugin script](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/268590/how-can-i-add-a-linkedin-plugin-script-in-a-stack-overflow-profiles-about-me) or no?
As I understand, I need to use my own link of stack exchange with photo or something in the same way.

```
https://stackexchange.com/users/11389854/invzbl3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what *description* you mean but let's assume it is your *About Me*. 
 Your flair image is [here](https://stackexchange.com/users/flair/11389854.png) and this is the url:

> `https://stackexchange.com/users/flair/11389854.png`

That number is your network accountid (which is different from your per-site userid)

This is how your flair looks:

[image: network flair]

and this is the markup you use:

```
![network flair](https://stackexchange.com/users/flair/11389854.png)
```

You can find the flair on your network profile, in the [flair tab](https://stackexchange.com/users/11389854/invzbl3?tab=flair)

Comment: In the question I wrote "inside description" as place where I want to add it. Thanks rene for helpful information. I'll try it and mark as solution if it helps me to realize.